# Pandas Finding Multiple Hierarchy Averages

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

Let's say I have data like below in a Pandas dataframe:

[image]

I would like to find descriptive statistics (mean, median, standard dev) of:

1. unique users per cohort
2. comments per user per cohort
3. comments per cohort

So for output, I'd expect to see:

1. unique users per cohort -> [{a:3},{b:2},...] and then finding descriptive statistics for the series
2. comments per user per cohort -> [{(a,alex):2},{(b,alex):0},{(a,beth):1},{(b,beth):3}...]
3. comments per cohort -> [{a:5}, {b:6}...]

I'm using Pandas, and I'm absolutely stuck on how to do something so simple. I was thinking of using `.groupby()`, but that didn't yield a clear solution. I could do this without Pandas, but I thought these were the kinds of questions a Pandas dataframe was made for!?

Thanks!

Comment: Some example output would be useful.

Comment: Added what I'd like to see. Thanks!

Comment: Please do not tag python/pands questions with [R] unless there is some good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

You could use

```
df.groupby(['Cohort', 'User']).describe()
```

or

```
df.groupby(['Cohort']).describe()
```

## Per your desired output

```
df.groupby(['Cohort'])['User'].apply(lambda x: x.describe().ix['unique'])
```

and

```
df.groupby(['Cohort', 'User'])['Comment'].apply(lambda x: x.describe().ix['unique'])
```

and

```
df.groupby(['Cohort'])['Comment'].apply(lambda x: x.describe().ix['unique'])
```

Comment: Those gives me descriptive statistics for the numeric values grouped by `['cohort', 'user']` but I'm interested in the grouping counts themselves. Thanks for helping!

Comment: I think that is it! I just added `.describe()` to the end and got the summary stats I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> df.groupby('Cohort').User.apply(lambda group: group.unique())
Cohort
a    [alex, beth, craig]
b          [beth, craig]
Name: User, dtype: object

>>> df.groupby('Cohort').User.apply(lambda group: group.nunique())
Out[40]: 
Cohort
a    3
b    2
Name: User, dtype: int64

>>> df.groupby(['Cohort', 'User']).Comment.count()
Out[43]: 
Cohort  User 
a       alex     2
        beth     1
        craig    2
b       beth     3
        craig    3
Name: Comment, dtype: int64

df.groupby(['Cohort']).Comment.count()
Out[44]: 
Cohort
a    5
b    6
Name: Comment, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks for this code. It's very helpful for better understanding what is going on.